# Leaving a Math PhD program in India to join another in the US or Europe

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, mathematics, united-states

I am currently a second year masters student in Math in India and I wish to go to the US or Europe for pursuing my PhD.

But due to a low GPA in my first year, I plan to apply next year after completing my masters with a decent aggregate GPA. This would also aid my application because I will have taken more advanced courses related to my research interest. Moreover, I need to save some money for an year so that I can pay the hefty TOEFL and GRE fees, not to mention the insane application fee per university.

Now since the grad school admission process is quite erratic (so have I heard), I also wish to join some grad school here in India just after my masters. That means I plan to be in the coursework phase of my PhD in India while applying for a PhD abroad.

Simple, straight query : Would it negatively affect my application?
Any advice/suggestion shall be highly appreciated.

Comment: How would the American school know you are already registered for a PhD in India, if you don't tell them?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are mentioning your difficulties to pay for GRE and TOEFL, I am wondering whether you will need a full scholarship in order to study in the US. Depending on the branch of Mathematics you are aspiring to, support can be hard to get and competitive. If your first year GPA is disappointing, and your GRE scores are not outstanding, you might be better off planing to study in India for your Ph.D.

If I were on the graduate admissions committee in the US, I would not care about you being currently enrolled in a Ph.D. program in India, but not every-one might have the same opinion. It could be seen as using up a rare resource.

The most important quality that admissions committees are looking for is the capability to do independent research. Publishing a paper is tough, but the best way to get into a good program.

Comment: I don't know if it's disappointing. It's 68%. But our courses are like grad level courses in the US (I have compared the coursework). I am in a top school of India but I am definitely not the top 10%. For reference, by the end of second year, I will have done graduate level courses in Modular Forms, Harmonic Analysis and Algebraic Number Theory. But yes, I will need a 100% scholarship to pursue my PhD abroad.

Answer (score 1):

I can share my personal experience and observation. I know PhD students (from India) who have quit to move abroad (US) to pursue a PhD. I had a classmate who pursued a PhD in his late 50s and successfully completed. Each application is different. My personal belief is: No, it would not affect your admission.

I took a Toefl, GRE and GRE physics (there is also gre math, please check with the department) 8 years ago and it was very expensive (since you mentioned costs). Like you pointed out, you need to account for the US admission fees. I can understand your concern. That said, most Universities outside of the US/Canada do not ask for GRE or GRE Math, they may ask for IELTS or TOEFL, if you go to an anglophone country. I don’t think they have an admission fee either. You could apply to those European institutions. US scholarships are offered for one year. You need it renewed every year, depending on the department's funding opportunities. I got paid as a TA, a fellowship for a summer, then as RA for the rest of the PhD. However, I have seen friends who had to teach for the rest of their PhD. I have never seen anyone pursue a PhD without funding. It sounds odd to me.

I have always thought that the GPA is not the ultimate reason for rejection. I’m nobody to judge your score, I’d probably score worse in math. It’s an accomplishment to get into a top school in India, it takes a lot of effort. What you need is a solid letter of recommendation, a well written statement of purpose (and good gre scores for US) and an attractive CV along with your GPA. Like you said, you can mention the advanced courses in your statement and maybe have a Professor comment on the courses you took in their letter of recommendation. A publication never hurts your admission and is an easy path but having zero published research is not a reason for rejection at this stage of career. Think of it as an application package. If you have an “unreasonable” score, you can explain it in your statement. If nothing works, you can always purse a PhD in India and then plan for the future.